# How to know when user has closed web application

Tags: java, javascript, html, angularjs, playframework

I have my web application built with Play Framework 2 (backend) and AngularJS (frontend).

I need to execute some clean up calls in my backend when the user quits my web application (either by closing the browser tab or logging out).

I use [play! Authenticate](http://joscha.github.io/play-authenticate/) plugin from Joscha Feth to handle logins and logouts, so I think I could call the global method

```
afterLogout()
```

to do the cleaning, but I don't know how to generate the event.

Javascript? Html? Anything else?

Comment: You can't control when user closes the browser window/tab, so the only option you have is firing your action through user logout action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to detect this.

Typically you will keep a session and any cleanups you need to perform run when the session is cleaned up as well (because that means the user has *left*, ie. you're going to forget about him/her).

You can try to use `onbeforeunload` but browsers heavily restrict what you can do here, since the browser really wants to shut down, it doesn't want to wait on your code to finish. Doing any kind of AJAX is very unreliable.

Comment: How can I intercept when the session is cleaned up (so that I can add my instructions) in Play Framework then?

Comment: I'm not familiar with playframework (or Java for that matter). See if they have a session manager, you'll want to hook into the garbage collect function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'm going to look into that.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  afterLogout();
};
```

Comment: This won't do. Note that this will be executed when closing **any** tab related with the web application.